# Can't get SQL query results to display on a JSP Page table?

Tags: java, sql, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

I am creating a dynamic web project using eclipse, following the MVC design. I am currently trying to get data from my sql table to display on a JSP page but it just comes back as blank. I am using JNDI datasorce for the connection which works fine. when l deploy the project to the server the table headers appear fine but with no data below.
Here’s my Code

JSP code

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>  
<head>  
<title>View All Students</title>  
</head>  
<body>  

<h1>Students List</h1>  

<table cellpadding="5" border=1>  

<tr valign="bottom">  
<th><%= request.getAttribute("Student_Id") %></th>  
<th>First Name</th>  
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Week 1</th> 
<th>Week 2</th>
<th>Week 3</th>
<th>Week 4</th>
<th>Week 5</th>
<th>Week 6</th>
<th>Week 7</th>
<th>Week 8</th>
<th>Week 9</th>
<th>Week 10</th>
<th>Week 11</th>
<th>Week 12</th>   
</tr>  
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>  
<c:forEach var="student" items="${viewAllStudents}">  
<tr valign="top">  
<td><p>${student.Student_Id}</td>  
<td><p>${student.firstName}</td>  
<td><p>${student.lastName}</td>
<td><p>${student.Week1}</td>
<td><p>${student.Week2}</td>
<td><p>${student.Week3}</td>
<td><p>${student.Week4}</td>
<td><p>${student.Week5}</td>
<td><p>${student.Week6}</td>
<td><p>${student.Week7}</td>
<td><p>${student.Week8}</td>
<td><p>${student.Week9}</td>
<td><p>${student.Week10}</td>
<td><p>${student.Week11}</td>
<td><p>${student.Week12}</td>
</tr>  
</c:forEach>  

</table>  

</body>  
</html>
```

Servelt (Controller) Code

```
    package uk.ac.qub.PTStudentView;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.naming.Context;
    import javax.naming.InitialContext;
    import javax.naming.NamingException;
    import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import javax.sql.DataSource;

    import uk.ac.qub.Beans.Student;
    import uk.ac.qub.LoginController.Account;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class PTStudentViewController
 */
@WebServlet("/PTStudentViewController")
public class PTStudentViewController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private DataSource ds;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public PTStudentViewController() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see Servlet#init(ServletConfig)
     */
    public void init(ServletConfig config)  throws ServletException {
        try {
            InitialContext initContext = new InitialContext();

            Context env = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env");

            ds = (DataSource) env.lookup("jdbc/testdb");

        } catch (NamingException e) {
            throw new ServletException();
        }
    }


    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {




        try {
            List<Student> viewAllStudents = PTViewStudent.list();
            request.setAttribute("students", viewAllStudents); // Will be available as ${students} in JSP
            request.getRequestDispatcher("ViewAllStudentsPage.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new ServletException("Cannot obtain products from DB", e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    }
```

Class for Sql statment

```
package uk.ac.qub.PTStudentView;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import uk.ac.qub.Beans.Student;

public class PTViewStudent {
private static Connection conn;

public PTViewStudent (Connection conn){
    this.conn = conn;
}

public static List<Student> list() throws SQLException{

    String sql = "select * from student where Student_Id = 666";
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    List<Student> viewAllStudents = new ArrayList<>();

    while(rs.next()){
        Student student = new Student();
        student.setId(rs.getInt("Student_Id"));
        student.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstName"));
        student.setLastName(rs.getString("lastName"));
        student.setWeek1(rs.getDouble("Week1"));
        student.setWeek2(rs.getDouble("Week2"));
        student.setWeek3(rs.getDouble("Week3"));
        student.setWeek4(rs.getDouble("Week4"));
        student.setWeek5(rs.getDouble("Week5"));
        student.setWeek6(rs.getDouble("Week6"));
        student.setWeek7(rs.getDouble("Week7"));
        student.setWeek8(rs.getDouble("Week8"));
        student.setWeek9(rs.getDouble("Week9"));
        student.setWeek10(rs.getDouble("Week10"));
        student.setWeek11(rs.getDouble("Week11"));
        student.setWeek12(rs.getDouble("Week12"));
        viewAllStudents.add(student);
    }
    return viewAllStudents;
}

}
```

Thanks For any help

Comment: try adding some debug code to see what's going on behind the scenes, also, it looks to me like your sql statement is selecting a hardcoded student id, you don't want that, unless that's just debug stuff

Comment: Im pretty new to all this tbh....yea the sql statment is just to get a quick result, I have been able to parse xml code into the table but now want to be able to view it on the JSP but cant work out how, im pretty sure its very close to being right but just dont know the problem

Comment: Yes it compiles...just doesnt populate the table....Im using a JNDI data source but dont know where in the Servelt to put it or what the code would be, like in the doGet method?

Answer (score 0):

I found your bug!

Right, so in your jsp, you have this line of code
`<c:forEach var="student" items="${viewAllStudents}">`
Which means, look in the request scope for a list called viewAllStudents, and then loop through them all

Which is valid, however, in your actual servlet code, you have this:
`List<Student> viewAllStudents = PTViewStudent.list();
request.setAttribute("students", viewAllStudents); // Will be available as ${students} in JSP
request.getRequestDispatcher("ViewAllStudentsPage.jsp").forward(request, response);`

Which is also valid, however, you need to change your JSTL to be this
`<c:forEach var="student" items="${students}">`

Comment: THANKS!! although the table is still appaearing with no records...am i missing code for the JNDI Datasource?

Comment: You never give your PTViewStudent class a connection object to work with, as far as your code is concerned, when you just call PTViewStudent.list() there is **no connection to query**

Comment: can the DB connection code be put in the list() method?

Comment: It could, but you still need a connection object, all you have is a datasource, not a connection.